# Javascript substitute for cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

In javascript, is there a clear and concise substitute for cookies? I am currently storing game saves in cookies, and looking for a way to make them harder to accidentally (or purposely) delete.

Comment: You can use localStorage, but they can clear that, too. Nothing is totally safe if it's stored on the user's computer instead of your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really not that many places to store data. You can really store it in two places:

1. The client's machine: There are other options besides cookies, but they are just as likely to be cleared if the user wishes. Cookies are probably still the easiest way to go about this.
2. Your server: You could create some login system or other to store the data locally and then determine what saved data corresponds to which client.

I still think your best option here is to use cookies. Most games rely on cookies or browser saved data anyways and clearing that within the browser deletes progress.

**If you really do not like cookies:**

With the introduction of HTML5 you can now save data within the browser, for more information see here: http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-web-storage/. This could allow for more data to be saved and speed up the requests, but also will probably get cleared if the user clears their cookies.

Comment: The reason i'm trying not to use cookies is because there are options to purchase perks, and if they clear their cookies, and lose paid for perks, I don't want to get caught up in trouble for improperly storing data, and being accused of possibly giving payPal info to a third party.

Comment: You should not be storing PayPal data on a user's system at all, or in your system. You shouldn't have access to it.

Comment: I don't have access to it, it was just an example

Comment: @wyattbergeron1 If you have paid options the best way is to create some sort of login system so that they can restore purchases or just do everything through the server.